# find the new path after using os.system('cd')

Tags: python, operating-system, python-os

I'm trying to generate windows CMD using os.
After I change the directory using os.system('cd other_dir'), how can I find the new directory, using os?

Comment: `os.system('cd other_dir')` is basically a no-op, since the `cd` is executed in a subshell. The working directory of your program won't change.

Answer (score 1):

How about standard Linux commands since you're at it:

```
os.system("pwd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
os.getcwd()
```

This will give you the current working directory (cwd).

Answer (score 0):

However, other fellows has already suggested the  the best possible answers, but i would like to add few more hints while using `os` module..

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("pwd")
/home/digit       # <-- this is listing the present working Dir
0
```

However its more feasible and wise to the us ethe `os` modules internal attributes for the usage like traversing into a directory like `os.chdir` rather using `os.system("cd /home/digit/openstack")` because it's more intuitive and os module feature.

So, traversing into a directory you should use `os.chdir` !

```
>>> os.chdir("openstack")
>>> os.system("pwd")
/home/dgit/openstack
0
```

Same applied for get the current dir information avoid using native os command while using python `os` module and rather use `os.getcwd`.

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/digit/openstack'
```

To list the current directory contents use `os.listdir` rather `os.system("ls -l")`

```
>>> os.listdir()
['vm_list.html']
```

OR, without specifying the current working directory path, this is more pythonic

```
>>> os.listdir(os.getcwd())
['vm_list.html']
```

OR, you can even use a for loop to list the files & directory to a specified Dir but more elegant way is above one!

```
>>> for filename in os.listdir("/home/digit/openstack"):
...     print(filename)
...
vm_list.html
```

In case you are looking only to get the subdirectories within a given Dir:

```
>>> os.chdir("/home/digit/plura/Test")

>>> next(os.walk('.'))[1]
['Python_Dump', 'File_Write_Method', 'Python_FTP', 'Python_Panda', 'Python-3.6.3', 'Python_Parsers', 'Python_Mail', 'Python_aritsTest', 'Network_DeOps', 'Python_ldap', 'Python_Ftp', 'Regular_Expr', 'Python_Primer', 'Python_excep', 'dnspython', '.git', 'argpass', 'BASH', 'NWK-old', 'tmp', 'Backup']
>>>
```